# Sci-fi novel about a future galactic Chinese empire and a concealed planet covered by a force field or mist

Tags: story-identification, books

It's about a future galactic Chinese empire and a concealed planet covered by a force field or mist. The concealed planet was not part of the galactic empire. It was a human space colony. The book was published during the period between 90s-2010s. I read it in English and not sure l think either light speed or FTL starships existed in the future.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. This isn't a lot to go on at the moment, could you please take a look at [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: Was this novel in Chinese or some other language? When did you read it? Do you remember any other details? For example, did starships use lightspeed engines or wormholes to travel? Any particulars in terms of uniforms or equipment?

Comment: Do you remember any plot points? Was there open warfare between the empire and the independent planet? Was it more of a spy/intrigue story?

Comment: This may be a garbled memory of Vernor Vinge's _A Deepness in the Sky_ with the Qeng He trading empire.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. Even without the edits, there was more than enough here to work with.

Comment: @Spencer Or a hazy through the mists of memory take on Frederic Pohl's *Black Star Rising*?

Answer (score 3):

I think this a garbled memory of Vernor Vinge's 1999 novel *[A Deepness in the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Deepness_in_the_Sky)*, which occurs in a star system dubbed "On/Off" because its sun turns on and off in a 250 year cycle.  The life on a planet in this system is adapted to this cycle, staying in hibernation on the frozen planet during the star's off periods and thawing out during warm periods.

The spider-like dominant species on this planet has developed technology to get itself to the start of the Industrial Revolution.

At the beginning of the movel, the star is about to turn back on, and the planet is expected to thaw out. There are two space polities vying for trade with the Spiders when they thaw out:

- the Qeng Ho, an interstellar trading empire (which is where I think you got the "Chinese Galactic Empire" idea from)
- the Emergents, entering an expansionist phase after being decimated by a plague (which enters into the action of the book).

This is a prequel to *A Fire Upon the Deep* and occurs within what the other novel would call the Slow Zone, where no FTL travel is possible.